# CUDA: Differences in precision when summing doubles on host and device?

Tags: c++, cuda, double, gpu

Just started experimenting with CUDA and I've hit a roadblock :(

I'm trying to sum a few double variables with high precision, but the result is staggeringly different (after the decimal point) when performing the addition on the device vs the host. I've tested the following sample code using nvcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

/// Kernel
__global__ void SolveRE(double x, double y, double z)
{
    printf("From GPU: %.15lf\n", (x*x + y*y + z*z));
}

int main ()
{
    // Define values
    double x = 3051774.263732617720962;
    double y = 7168331.130877199582756;
    double z = 983.741348489015081;

    // Call kernel
    SolveRE<<<1, 1>>>(x, y, z);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Print from host
    printf("From CPU: %.15lf\n", (x*x + y*y + z*z));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
From GPU: 60698298326430.984375000000000
From CPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
```

I assume this discrepancy has something to do with floating-point operation precision? Or am I missing something more? Any way to get the results to align with one another?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) *might* be relevant.

Comment: compile with `-fmad=false` and I believe the results will line up.  This disables fused-multiply-add operations on the GPU.  This is a good indication that the GPU result is actually more accurate than the CPU result, although I'm not demonstrating any proof of that here.  You may wish to read the [nvcc manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) for switch syntax, and also the [floating point whitepaper](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html).

Comment: I would guess the CPU version is reporting a constant calculated by the compiler. And the error is in the 17th digit, which isn't much.

Comment: `60698298326430.9921875` is the closest double to the correct answer which according to [speedcrunch](https://speedcrunch.org/) is `60698298326430.99276076796155137957`

Comment: I did the calculation exactly, using Java's BigDecimal, and got 60698298326430.992760767961597288006432286790226531201218086730708733966821455396711826324462890625, agreeing with @AlanBirtles results.

Comment: Yes, I got a similar result using the calculator built into windows 10 (`.9927607...`).   So I withdraw my statement about accuracy.  According to my testing the results between GPU and CPU line up exactly if you compile with `fmad=false`.  So I suspect the fused-multiply-add being performed in the GPU calculation is affecting its result.

Comment: When looking at such low significance bits, which gets the closer result can depend on the inputs. Why does such a tiny difference matter in the application, and can that be changed?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Setting the fmad flag seems to have done the trick, thanks! Is there any notable disadvantages to using this though (speed, accuracy, etc)? Alan suggests that the CPU result is actually more accurate in this case, but I assume this isn't always the case?

Comment: The accuracy of the CPU and GPU are comparable, but again, you are not looking at a CPU result. You are looking at a constant which was likely calculated in higher precision and correctly rounded

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan My aim is to implement some basic CUDA methods into an existing simulator. Right now, some of the output results of the simulator are being impacted by these errors, so I want to ensure that the exact same results are produced in both the original and "CUDA-fied" versions :)

Comment: It can affect calculation speed. I am also certain that in some calculations it can result in a less accurate result (a result that may still agree with the calculation on another platform such as CPU), and once again I'm not advancing a proof point here. It's OK with me if you don't believe me without proof. I'm not going to make any statements about what is "always the case" when comparing CPU and GPU floating point results, especially if you are asking for bit-wise identical results. The results between the two platforms will often differ. I've suggested the FP whitepaper, it's worth a read

Comment: @RobertCrovella Much appreciated. I think I'll go with the fmad suggestion for now - hopefully it'll work out in the long term. I'll accept your comment as the solution if you post it as an answer :)

Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: The accuracy discrepancy on the GPU side seems to come about due to order of operations.  The compiler is free to choose in whatever order to sum the results of the squares.  If the code is modified so that `double y = 3051774.263732617720962; double z = 7168331.130877199582756; double x = 983.741348489015081;` you'll see matching results between GPU and CPU (even without `-fmad=false`).  As already pointed out in the answer, the CPU result here is actually being precomputed by the compiler, so it is conceivably also subject to these variations if computed on the fly, depending on ordering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been discussed in comments, the root cause appears to be FMAD instruction generation on the GPU. I don't have access a system to test what result would be generated if FMA3/FMA4 instructions were used to use CPU side FMADD instructions. The result might be different under such conditions.

However, you need to be *extremely* careful when looking at examples like this because what you are seeing isn't necessarily attributable to CPU versus GPU differences.

To show what I mean look at a simplified (and more complex) version of your host code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

double func(double x, double y, double z, bool docalc=true)
{
    if (docalc) {
        return x*x + y*y + z*z;
    } else {
        double xp = 3051774.263732617720962;
        double yp = 7168331.130877199582756;
        double zp =     983.741348489015081;
        return xp*xp + yp*yp + zp*zp;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    // Define values
    double x = 3051774.263732617720962;
    double y = 7168331.130877199582756;
    double z =     983.741348489015081;

    // Print from host
    double val = func(x, y, z);
    double valp = func(x, y, z, false);
    printf("From CPU: %.15lf\n", val);
    printf("From CPU: %.15lf\n", valp);

    return 0;
}
```

compiled, run, and disassembled like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -o doubleh doubleh.cc
$./doubleh
From CPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
From CPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
$ objdump -d doubleh

....
0000000000000560 <main>:
 560:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 564:   48 8d 35 09 02 00 00    lea    0x209(%rip),%rsi        # 774 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 56b:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 570:   c5 fb 10 05 10 02 00    vmovsd 0x210(%rip),%xmm0        # 788 <_IO_stdin_used+0x18>
 577:   00 
 578:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 57d:   e8 be ff ff ff          callq  540 <__printf_chk@plt>
 582:   c5 fb 10 05 fe 01 00    vmovsd 0x1fe(%rip),%xmm0        # 788 <_IO_stdin_used+0x18>
 589:   00 
 58a:   48 8d 35 e3 01 00 00    lea    0x1e3(%rip),%rsi        # 774 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 591:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 596:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 59b:   e8 a0 ff ff ff          callq  540 <__printf_chk@plt>
 5a0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 5a2:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 5a6:   c3                      retq   
 5a7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 5ae:   00 00
```

The result is the correct result, which is no surprise. But note there is no function call and no floating point arithmetic in the assembly. The compiler has in-lined and optimized away both function calls and replaced them with two compile time constants. So the result you see, while correct, wasn't computed at runtime and says nothing about what the CPU would actually do if your code was run.

So let's go to the GPU:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
__device__ __host__ double func(double x, double y, double z, bool docalc=true)
{
    if (docalc) {
        return x*x + y*y + z*z;
    } else {
        double xp = 3051774.263732617720962;
        double yp = 7168331.130877199582756;
        double zp =     983.741348489015081;
        return xp*xp + yp*yp + zp*zp;
    }
}

/// Kernel
__global__ void SolveRE(double x, double y, double z, bool docalc=true)
{
    double val = func(x,y,z, docalc);
    printf("From GPU: %.15lf\n", val);
}

int main ()
{
    // Define values
    double x = 3051774.263732617720962;
    double y = 7168331.130877199582756;
    double z =     983.741348489015081;

    // Call kernel
    SolveRE<<<1, 1>>>(x, y, z);
    SolveRE<<<1, 1>>>(x, y, z, false);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Print from host
    double val = func(x, y, z);
    double valp = func(x, y, z, false);
    printf("From CPU: %.15lf\n", val);
    printf("From CPU: %.15lf\n", valp);

    return 0;
}
```

Again compiled, run and disassembled:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 --fmad=true -o double double.cu
$ ./double
From GPU: 60698298326430.984375000000000
From GPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
From CPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
From CPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000

$ cuobjdump -ptx double

.version 6.4
.target sm_52
.address_size 64


.visible .entry _Z7SolveREdddb(
.param .f64 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_0,
.param .f64 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_1,
.param .f64 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_2,
.param .u8 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_3
)
{
.local .align 8 .b8 __local_depot0[8];
.reg .b64 %SP;
.reg .b64 %SPL;
.reg .pred %p<2>;
.reg .b16 %rs<3>;
.reg .b32 %r<2>;
.reg .f64 %fd<8>;
.reg .b64 %rd<5>;


mov.u64 %SPL, __local_depot0;
cvta.local.u64 %SP, %SPL;
ld.param.f64 %fd1, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_0];
ld.param.f64 %fd2, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_1];
ld.param.f64 %fd3, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_2];
add.u64 %rd1, %SP, 0;
add.u64 %rd2, %SPL, 0;
ld.param.s8 %rs1, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_3];
and.b16 %rs2, %rs1, 255;
setp.eq.s16 %p1, %rs2, 0;
mul.f64 %fd4, %fd2, %fd2;
fma.rn.f64 %fd5, %fd1, %fd1, %fd4;
fma.rn.f64 %fd6, %fd3, %fd3, %fd5;
selp.f64    %fd7, 0d42CB9A36414ECF7F, %fd6, %p1;
st.local.f64 [%rd2], %fd7;
mov.u64 %rd3, $str;
cvta.global.u64 %rd4, %rd3;

    {
.reg .b32 temp_param_reg;

    .param .b64 param0;
st.param.b64    [param0+0], %rd4;
.param .b64 param1;
st.param.b64    [param1+0], %rd1;
.param .b32 retval0;
call.uni (retval0), 
vprintf, 
(
param0, 
param1
);
ld.param.b32    %r1, [retval0+0];


    }
    ret;
}
```

You can see that the GPU produces two different results! The GPU compiler has done exactly what the host compiler did -- optimize away floating point and replace it with a constant when it identifies it can do so safely.

Turning off FMAD instructions removes the difference and changes the device code emitted by the compiler:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 --fmad=false -o double double.cu
$ cuobjdump -ptx double


.version 6.4
.target sm_52
.address_size 64



.visible .entry _Z7SolveREdddb(
.param .f64 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_0,
.param .f64 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_1,
.param .f64 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_2,
.param .u8 _Z7SolveREdddb_param_3
)
{
.local .align 8 .b8 __local_depot0[8];
.reg .b64 %SP;
.reg .b64 %SPL;
.reg .pred %p<2>;
.reg .b16 %rs<3>;
.reg .b32 %r<2>;
.reg .f64 %fd<10>;
.reg .b64 %rd<5>;


mov.u64 %SPL, __local_depot0;
cvta.local.u64 %SP, %SPL;
ld.param.f64 %fd1, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_0];
ld.param.f64 %fd2, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_1];
ld.param.f64 %fd3, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_2];
add.u64 %rd1, %SP, 0;
add.u64 %rd2, %SPL, 0;
ld.param.s8 %rs1, [_Z7SolveREdddb_param_3];
and.b16 %rs2, %rs1, 255;
setp.eq.s16 %p1, %rs2, 0;
mul.rn.f64 %fd4, %fd1, %fd1;
mul.rn.f64 %fd5, %fd2, %fd2;
add.rn.f64 %fd6, %fd4, %fd5;
mul.rn.f64 %fd7, %fd3, %fd3;
add.rn.f64 %fd8, %fd6, %fd7;
selp.f64    %fd9, 0d42CB9A36414ECF7F, %fd8, %p1;
st.local.f64 [%rd2], %fd9;
mov.u64 %rd3, $str;
cvta.global.u64 %rd4, %rd3;

    {
.reg .b32 temp_param_reg;

    .param .b64 param0;
st.param.b64    [param0+0], %rd4;
.param .b64 param1;
st.param.b64    [param1+0], %rd1;
.param .b32 retval0;
call.uni (retval0), 
vprintf, 
(
param0, 
param1
);
ld.param.b32    %r1, [retval0+0];


    }
    ret;
}


$ ./double
From GPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
From GPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
From CPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
From CPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
```

None of this changes the fact that the source of the difference in your example is GPU FMAD instruction generation, but *cavaet emptor*, compilers are a lot smarter than you think and they do things which can easily invalidate comparisons, such as the one in your question.

Comment: Will need to be careful then. I'll keep an eye on any unexpected differences which arise. Thanks for the detailed example! :)

Answer (score 3):

The discrepancy between the CPU and GPU result here is coming about due not to fused-multiply-add, but due to order of operations.  As indicated in the other answer, the first item to "fix" in the comparison is to allow the CPU result to be actually computed by runtime code, as opposed to precomputed by the compiler.  If we then simply reorder the `x`,`y`, and `z` operands, we can reverse the result, such that the CPU result is now the one that is farther from the correctly rounded result than the GPU result:

```
$ cat t1699.cu
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

/// Kernel
__global__ void SolveRE(double x, double y, double z)
{
    printf("From GPU: %.15lf\n", (x*x + y*y + z*z));
}


double SolveRE_CPU(double x, double y, double z){

  return (x*x + y*y + z*z);
}

int main ()
{
    // Define values
    double z = 3051774.263732617720962;
    double x = 7168331.130877199582756;
    double y = 983.741348489015081;

    // Call kernel
    SolveRE<<<1, 1>>>(x, y, z);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Print from host
    printf("From CPU: %.15lf\n", SolveRE_CPU(x, y, z));

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1699 t1699.cu
$ ./t1699
From GPU: 60698298326430.992187500000000
From CPU: 60698298326430.984375000000000
$
```

Now, in this situation, compiling with `-fmad=false` will once again line up the two results (GPU result will become the same as the CPU result listed above, which is the "less accurate" result), but this is not due to any effect of the fused-multiply-add operation itself, but instead because the (GPU) compiler is choosing a different order of evaluation of the intermediate results.

Comment: Interesting. I'll definitely need to mention this in my write-up, haha. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!